# How empty spaces are taken in python for pattern problem where characters wants to print in multiple symbol structure?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, whitespace

In pattern program where characters are wants to print in multiple symbol structure like this.

```
 *       *
   *   *
     *
   *   *
*        *
```

I write a for loop condition for two crosses separately and it give out correctly but if i merge both conditions then it won't give the right output why?

The code for first cross is

```
 n='apple'
    for i in range(len(n)):
        print('  '*i+n[i])
```

First i print the empty string for spaces that needs to leave by i times because each line the empty space takes starting from 0 and increment by 1 for len(string)-1 times.

Then i would print the character from the given string,so the output would be .

```
a         
  p    
    p
       l
         e
```

For second cross the code is

```
n='apple'
for i in range(len(n)):
    print('  '*(len(n)-(i+1))+n[(len(n)-1)-i])
```

Instead of printing the character from the begining it starts from end and the characters are also in reverse order so this output would be .

```
        e
      l
    p
  p
a
```

But the problem is when i merge this code like this.

```
n='apple'
for i in range(len(n)):
    print('  '*i+n[i]+'  '*(len(n)-(i+1))+n[(len(n)-1)-i])
```

It output is vary why?

```
a         e
  p       p
    p     p
      l   l
         ea
```

Comment: That normal, because with the concatenation, the 2nd lettre is always after the first. But in the expected output, the 2nd letter is expected before the 1st at the end

Answer (score 1):

I see that the code is overcomplicated. I was able to break it to the separate lines like so:

```py
n='apple'
for i in range(len(n)):
    print(
        '  ' * i  # '', '  ', '    '...
        + n[i]  # 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'
        + '  ' * (
            len(n) - (i + 1)  # (5 - 1), (5 - 2), (5 - 3) , (5 - 4), (5 - 5): 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
        )
        + n[(len(n) - 1) - i]
    )
```

So the problem here is this line `len(n) - (i + 1)`. It causes the algorithm to multiply empty spaces after the first printed letter regardless of the second letter (that one that prints apple backwards): first, it would be 8 spaces, then 6, then 4, 2, 0.

I suggest you break down this single `print` row into separate steps to understand what's going on here. Like so:

```py
WORD = 'apple'
SPACES = '  '
SIZE = len(SPACES * len(WORD))
TEMPLATE = list(' ' * SIZE)

for i, first_char in enumerate(WORD):
    second_char = WORD[len(WORD) - 1 - i]

    first_char_position = len(SPACES * i)
    second_char_position = len(TEMPLATE) - len(SPACES * i) - 2

    curr_row = TEMPLATE.copy()
    curr_row[first_char_position] = first_char
    curr_row[second_char_position] = second_char

    print(''.join(curr_row))
```